# How to create a custom arrow in the material table Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to the Angular Material. Is there any way to override the mat-header-arrow in the material table. I have tried to make the mat-sort-header-container to display: none. But unfortunately it didn't work. 

Current Behavior:

[image: Current Behavior:]

Expected Behavior:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

Do one thing. Add following `CSS` code to your main stylesheet (Not component based)

`style.css`

```
.mat-sort-header-stem {
  background: none;
  display: none!important;
}

.mat-sort-header-pointer-middle{
  background: none;
  display: none!important;
}

.mat-sort-header-indicator{
  top: 5px!important;
}
```

**Result :**

[image: Result]

Comment: It is working. Thanks! Could we some different icon instead caret?

Comment: They are not using any specific icons, Its `<div>` with background color. So I don't think we can use any other fonts.